# Laravel 5.5 change password encryption on login

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, authentication

I want to change the Laravel's default password encyption. I want to use my own.
For the registration I know how I can do it: in the RegisterController I can change the bcrypt function

```
/**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

But where do I change how the login checks if the password is valid ?

Comment: any update on my answer ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your own logic to check passwords in this case and then use the `loginUsingId()` method:

```
if (yourMethodForPasswordCheck($request->password, $user->password)) {
    auth()->loginUsingId($user->id);
}
```

Or you could use `login()` method and pass User instance:

```
if (yourMethodForPasswordCheck($request->password, $user->password)) {
    auth()->login($user);
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#other-authentication-methods

Answer (score 0):

check with [`Hash::check`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/hashing)

```
if (Hash::check('secret', $hashedPassword))
{
    // The passwords match...
}
```

or

```
$userdata = array(
    'email'     => Input::get('email'),
    'password'  => Input::get('password')
);

// attempt to do the login
if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {
   // success
}
```

---

Can log using

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Auth::login($user); or
Auth::loginUsingId(1, true); # true is remeber me option
```

Comment: `Hash::check()` will not work if OP doesn't use Laravel's `bcrypt()` or `Hash::make()`

Comment: Thanks. he's using `'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),`

Comment: He says he will change it from `bcrypt()` to something else.

Comment: Yes. if he change, obviously he can use `Hash::make()`