# Laravel Authentication questions

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm pretty new to laravel and i made myself some question about authentication.
When I use the function Auth::attempt($credentials), it seems that laravel automatically encrypt in bcrypt,but what field?
I found that it automatically encrypt the 'password' field in the database, correct?
what if I would like to encrypt password in sha1?
Last but not less important, what is the benefit of using this function instead of a raw sql select query?
I'm working on improving my English.

Comment: Why: because safety. You should NEVER EVER, UNDER NO CIRCUMSTANCE store passwords in plain text. This prevents among others reading the passwords in plaintext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel is a smart framewrok. When you use `Auth::attempt($credentials)`, laravel simply search for the password field in the $credentials array and bcrypt it.

If you like to encrypt the value to sha1, you are free to do that. But for that, you have to make your custom functions to generate the sha1 encrypted value. Which i do not usually suggest.

Using a laravel Eloquent makes the codes clean and its easy to understand. Its not that you can not use the raw sql query. You can use that using `DB::selectRaw('query')->get()->toArray();` method. But the code seems messy.

Comment: Thank you for ur answer. What field does it encrypt? The field in the form named "password"?

Comment: yes. It searches for the field name password to use bcrypt method. Which is one of the strong encryption algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it uses Bcrypt. From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/hashing):

> The Laravel Hash facade provides secure Bcrypt hashing for storing user passwords.

If you want to use another hashing method, you'll not be able to use `attempt()`. In this case, you'll need to check password manually and [login user manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48209571/1227923).